# How to get the redirected status message from the url to the jsp page?

Tags: spring, jsp, url

This is the catch block for upload fail functionality.

```
catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("uploadFailureStatus", ServerMessageKeys.UPLOAD_FAILURE.getCode());
        }
```

if upload fails, in the url i will get like

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/....../masterInfo?uploadFailureStatus=upload.failure.status

I have to show that status message in the jsp page.
Pleae help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get parameter value using jsp request object.

i.e. `request.getParameter('uploadFailureStatus');`